# Volume control on ASUS Xonar DG in Xubuntu

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, volume-control

So from what I've gathered, there is no way to have volume control with my Xonar DG? This soundcard has already given me problems in Windows but having no volume control seems ridiculous.

http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Module-oxygen#Software_volume_control

That page is the only thing I have found and I need to dump a bunch of settings into a file in order to make it work. Which I did, but all that did for me was remove the existing control I had and broke everything. (I couldn't use the FN+F1 keys in order to mute for example) So do I just have to sit there and manually tweak everything with Pulse Audio Control? Because that will only lead to me accidentally opening some loud application and it blowing my ears out since I'm wearing headphones that don't have their own volume control.

Is there nothing I can do to make it work?

Comment: That hardware indeed has no volume control. You need the ALSA `softvol` plugin only when you're not using PulseAudio.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems pretty complicated to get this going, I'm still rather new with Linux but I'll give it a try. Hopefully I'll be able to undo it all if it goes wrong.

Comment: Do I have to install the plugin or is it already ready for usage? Since it doesn't seem to work and there is no mention of if you need to install it or not.

Edit: Nevermind wikipedia says it is preinstalled, so I guess I'm just doign something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the ASUS Xonar DGX when using headphones, perhaps the solution can be applied to your card as well.

First, check the available modes for "Analog Output":

```
$ amixer -c 0

[...]    
Simple mixer control 'Analog Output',0
  Capabilities: penum
  Items: 'Stereo Headphones' 'Stereo Headphones FP' 'Multichannel'
  Item0: 'Multichannel'
```

When this set to "Multichannel", volume control does not work. Set it to "Stereo Headphones" to enable the internal amplifier.

```
$ amixer -c 0 set "Analog Output" "Stereo Headphones"
Simple mixer control 'Analog Output',0
  Capabilities: penum
  Items: 'Stereo Headphones' 'Stereo Headphones FP' 'Multichannel'
  Item0: 'Stereo Headphones'
```

Answer (score 0):

This site won't let me comment on the previous answer. It worked for me. Thanks Stephen. Just to add, in my case

```
amixer -c 2
```

worked because I have a burnt out internal Realtek card, Nvidia's HDMI audio and Asus DG Xonar.